# Конвертировать HTML to RTF .net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

Есть какой нибудь пример или библиотека что бы конвертировать html в Rtf на .net Core

Comment: [30 секунд гугла](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5922740/12888024)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Однажды тоже столкнулся с этим вопросом, вот инфа, которая поможет (хоть её очень просто найти):

- Можно использовать продукт от [Sautinsoft](https://sautinsoft.ru/products/html-to-rtf/index.php). Я думаю этот вариант решает вообще все проблемы
- У меня была ситуация, когда не было возможности пользоваться продуктом от [Sautinsoft](https://sautinsoft.ru/products/html-to-rtf/index.php) поэтому я парсил контент html с помощью [HtmlAlightlyPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) и благодаря [документации по rtf](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm) (ссылку оставил на 1.5, но это далеко не самая новая версия) на коленке слепил свой мини конвертер ;) **Лучше так не делать!!!**
- Я искал методы как это можно сделать без библиотек, но они мне не подошли (с этого началась история 2 пункта). Но я думаю, что ссылка на решение от *aepot* отлично подойдёт